# Empty warning message when trying to favorite a question with expired session

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks, error-message

I very often use my working PC remotely and do not turn it off / reboot for weeks - I simply disconnect LogMeIn session and that's it. Sometimes browser remains untouched **overnight** or even **all over the weekend**. So, today I remotely connected to my PC, opened minimized browser which was left yesterday having one SO question opened. I decided to favorite it, but after click on star I got the following message:

[image: Star click]

Being QA, these things do not surprise me at all - I immediately realized the session has expired overnight. Indeed, after page refresh I got `log in` link:

[image: log in]

And just for comparison - I had my acc page opened on the other tab and tried to open `SE Inbox`:

[image: inbox error]

No doubts that one is OK and "by design" - at least user has an explanation.

QA at your service.

P.S. Testing environment (for the record): `Win7 Ultimate SP1 x64 / FF 19.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be a proper error message for that case starting with the next build.

Comment: Great, will validate it tomorrow as soon as new code is deployed. Browser window will be left opened overnight.

Comment: But, @Peter, *maybe* the fix is in the JavaScript, for which the old version is already loaded in your browser then. I assume a page refresh will also destroy your current test case. (Kevin, if you read this and I am wrong, then of course feel free to simply delete this comment. Quicker than commenting. `;-)`)

Comment: Do you mean I should clear browser cache beforehand? Frankly I don't understand what's wrong about my - or my FF - JavaScript......

Comment: @Kevin `You must be logged in to vote` is pretty nice, thanks! QA passed and closed.